# Does Stack Exchange make any money with the mobile app?

Tags: discussion, mobile-app, business-model, business

I recently wondered, what the business model of Stack Exchange is. As there were already several questions to this, I found a satisfying answer. 
But I'm often using the mobile application, and there are neither advertisements displayed, nor are there any job listings etc. shown. 
So I wondered, whether/how Stack Exchange makes any money/profit with their application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Does Stack Exchange make any money with the mobile app?

No, at least not directly.
The apps are just part of the total user experience Stack Exchange provides, just like the mobile version of the sites, which don't have any ads either. The idea is that by making it easier to participate on Stack Exchange, you make the users more committed, which increases page views on the normal site which does show ads.

Comment: But I don't think it would be that hard to implement, so why forgo it? Speaking for me, I would have no problem with some ads, and I don't think others do to, as the site provides great service. (As long as the ads are no videos or annoying pop-ups).

Comment: Yes, it's hard, because Stack Exchange wants only 'relevant' ads and can't rely on Apple's and Android's ad framework, and the ad sizes and requirements for mobile are very different from desktop browser ads. Also, development on the apps is frozen at the moment.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. The ads of android/apple are indeed not very relevant/useful. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser Unless you are interested in dating-websites , viagra-generica or parking your money in some goofy investment-fond ;)